# Object color changed when apply GLSL shader reflection in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

When i am  applying reflection to my object , object color changed not getting the proper color.without reflection its working fine. But when i applied reflection color changed.Kindly help? Where is my vertex and fragment shader..

```
   vertex_shader =
    uniform float mRefractionRatio;
    uniform float mFresnelBias;
    uniform float mFresnelScale;
    uniform float mFresnelPower;
    varying vec3 vReflect;
    varying vec3 vRefract[3];
    varying float vReflectionFactor;
    attribute vec3 a_normal;
    varying vec3 v_normal;
    varying vec3 v_position;
    uniform mat3 u_normalMatrix;
    void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    v_position = mvPosition.xyz;
    vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    vec3 worldNormal = normalize( mat3( modelMatrix[0].xyz, modelMatrix[1].xyz, modelMatrix[2].xyz ) * normal );
    vec3 I = worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition;
    vReflect = reflect( I, worldNormal );
    v_normal = u_normalMatrix * a_normal;
    vRefract[0] = refract( normalize( I ), worldNormal, 0.02 );
    vRefract[1] = refract( normalize( I ), worldNormal, 0.02 * 0.2);
    vRefract[2] = refract( normalize( I ), worldNormal, 0.02 * 0.2 );
    vReflectionFactor = 0.1 + 1.0 * pow( 1.0 + dot( normalize( I ), worldNormal ), 0.2 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;};



    fragment_shader =
    uniform samplerCube tCube;
    varying vec3 vReflect;
    varying vec3 vRefract[3];
    varying float vReflectionFactor;
    uniform vec4 u_ambient;
    uniform vec4 u_emission;
    uniform vec4 u_specular;
    uniform vec4 u_diffuse;
    varying vec3 v_normal;
    varying vec3 v_position;
    varying vec3 u_reflectivity;
    void main() {
    vec4 color = vec4(0., 0., 0., 1);
    vec3 diffuseLight = vec3(0., 0., 0.);
    vec3 u_light2Color = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    vec3 u_light1Color = vec3(0.5,1.0,1.0);
    vec4 diffuse = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 specularLight = vec3(0.5, 0.5,0.5);
    vec4 reflectedColor = textureCube( tCube, vec3( -vReflect.x, vReflect.yz ) );
    vec4 refractedColor = vec4(1 );
    refractedColor.r = textureCube( tCube, vec3( -vRefract[0].x, vRefract[0].yz ) ).r;
    refractedColor.g = textureCube( tCube, vec3( -vRefract[1].x, vRefract[1].yz ) ).g;
    refractedColor.b = textureCube( tCube, vec3( -vRefract[2].x, vRefract[2].yz ) ).b;
    gl_FragColor = mix( color, reflectedColor, clamp( vReflectionFactor, 0.0, 1.0 ) );
    };
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to achieve. So without reflection (and refraction) I am assuming you get black because `vec4 color = vec4(0., 0., 0., 1);`

Comment: Also, you end the post with "Where is my vertex and fragment shader"..... ????

Comment: It looks to me like you might be copying and pasting from some more complicated source. Maybe taking a look at [some basic shader examples](https://2pha.com/blog/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial/) would help.

Comment: I am new in three.js and i want achive cubic reflection in my object.But When i am applying reflcetion code from three.js meshlambert_frag and meshlambert_vert is applied to my material,model not coming black but my cubic env color is added to the object. Not getting adjact color with reflaction.var reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
 envMap: textureCube,
} );
// reflection on
object=Containing gltf file with PBR effect;
object.traverse(function(child) {
 if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
  child.material = reflectionMaterial;
 }
});

Comment: the last line `gl_FragColor` mixes the color and refelectedColor, but your color is black., so, if your reflection color is blue (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), and you add it to black (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), you will just get blue (0.0, 0.0, 1.0). You have alot of variables in the posted glsl code that are not being used, maybe remove them and it will be clearer.

Comment: The amount by which they are mixed is controlled by `vReflectionFactor`, my above comment assumed this is 1.0